# Matrices similar to nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence, similar-matrices

> Find a finite set of $n\times n$ matrices (specific number) with complex elements so that every nilpotent $n\times n$ matrix with complex elements is similar to only one of them.

I tried to think a general form of nilpotent matrix but I can't find one. Also I think that every nilpotent is similar to other nilpotents so how can it be finite set? Any hints?

Comment: Just find all possible Jordan normal forms; see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848502/find-all-possible-jordan-canonical-forms-for-a-nilpotent-matrix).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What can you say about the Jordan normal form of a nilpotent matrix?

Comment: Eigenvalues are zero so jordan is also a nilpotent. You mean the set I look for is the jordan matrices?

Comment: @GeorgeF Yes. Think about it. For instance, when $n=2$, one matrix is enough. And when $n=3$, $2$ matrices are enough.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Won't $n=2$ need two matrices? Since the Jordan normal form of a nilpotent matrix can be either $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and these two aren't similar.

Comment: @lisyarus Sure! I forgot the null matrix. And when $n=3$, $3$ matrices are enough.